# Tkinter - Listbox with scrollbar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

In my code I want to add some widgets in a Listbox widget, so I can later use a Scrollbar on it. The problem here is that the listbox will keep expanding no matter how many widgets I put in it, and the scrollbar is unusable since it does not update. How can I solve this issue?

```
from tkinter import *    

def pr_deleteChart():
    global _plotDictionary

    #_F_delChart.iconbitmap('ContaParole_icona.ico')

    _F_mainUpper = Frame(_root)
    _F_mainUpper.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = "nsew")

    _F_mainLower = Frame(_root)
    _F_mainLower.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = "sew")

    #listbox scrollbar
    _S_ListBoxScrollBar = Scrollbar(_F_mainUpper,orient = "vertical")
    _S_ListBoxScrollBar.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "nse")

    #Main listbox
    _L_mainListBox = Listbox(_F_mainUpper)
    _L_mainListBox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

    _S_ListBoxScrollBar.config(command = _L_mainListBox.yview)

    #Carico lista di chiavi
    keysList = list(_graphReferences.keys())

    #Per ogni grafico salvo variabile, checkButton e salvo tutto dentro _plotDictionary
    for index in range(0,len(keysList)):

        button = Checkbutton(_L_mainListBox, text = keysList[index])
        button.grid(row = index, column = 0, sticky = "nw")

if __name__== "__main__":

    _root = Tk()
    _root.title("Main window")
    _root.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

    _graphReferences = {"1":"2","3":"4","5":"6","7":"8","9":"10","11":"12"}

    pr_deleteChart()
```

Comment: When I run your code I get `NameError: name 'item' is not defined`. Fixing that yields another error, and fixing that yields another problem. Please create a working [mcve]

Comment: Now it should work.

Comment: Your comment says you want to add widgets to a Text widget, but there's no Text widget in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scroll items added to a listbox with `grid`, `pack`, or `place`. The scrollbar associated with a listbox will only scroll items added to the listbox with the `insert` method of the listbox.